# How to disable screensaver in TightVNC server and how to check the status whether screensaver is enabled or disabled

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

How to disable screensaver in TightVNC server and how to check the status whether screensaver is enabled or disabled?
I have tried with the method mention in one article but it did not worked.
To disable the screensaver for good, open the .xsession file through the following command:
$ sudo nano $HOME/.xsession
Then, add the following line and save the file:
xset s off
Then to see the changes we need to restart the system but it did not work. Is there any alternative method to disable the screensaver ?